# How to remember coordinates of mouseclick event to the List?

Tags: c#, list, graphics, mouseclick-event

I need that to program polygon-fill with Scanline algorithm.

but how i still don't know how to get coordinates of mouseclick and save this in list then get next point and do the same and i don't know how many times i will need to do that

Comment: On the mousedown event add the location of the mouse to a list of points in whatever class is handling the drawing of the polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the `MouseUp` event instead of the `Click` event. `MouseUp` event has a `MouseEventArgs` that contains the `X`, `Y` coordinates.

Comment: User can end with a double click. The MouseEventArgs of MouseUp has a Clicks property; Check for 2 on this property and do your algorithm there.

Answer (score 0):

In MouseClick event handler MouseEventArgs contain x and y coordinates of mouse cursor. Coordinates are control related.